# Auto submit does not get triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the file to be auto submitted to the form, once the user selects a file. I don't want the user to click the submit button

Here is the html

```
<input id="upload-profile" style="-webkit-user-select: text;" type="file" name="profile_pic[attachment]">
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="submit" class="submit-profile-pic" style="-webkit-user-select: text;">
```

Here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#upload-profile').change(function(event) {
        /* Act on the event */
        console.log("it went inside the event");
        $('submit-profile-pic').click();
    });

});
```

I have tried both submit and click, both does not work .. how ever manually clicking the submit button submits the form .. can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot

```
$('submit-profile-pic').click();
```

Should be

```
$('.submit-profile-pic').click();
```

As an alternative you could also use

```
$('form').submit();
```

Note: if you have multiple forms on your page, use the class or id as selector.

Comment: oops, I over looked .. sorry